# flutter How do I make the elements of List break to the second line after reaching the screen?

Tags: flutter, dart

flutter How do I make the elements of List break to the second line after reaching the screen?

This is the problem:

[the problem[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36o5X.jpg)

this the code:

```
    Wrap(
      children: [
        Row(
          children: scoreKeeper,
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly add children inside wrap.. assuming scorekeeper is a list of widget

```
Wrap(
 children: scoreKeeper,
 ),
```